# What's the point of Perl's map?

Tags: list, perl, dictionary, higher-order-functions

Not really getting the point of the map function. Can anyone explain with examples its use?

Are there any performance benefits to using this instead of a loop or is it just sugar?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Any time you want to generate a list based another list:

```
# Double all elements of a list
my @double = map { $_ * 2 } (1,2,3,4,5);
# @double = (2,4,6,8,10);
```

Since lists are easily converted pairwise into hashes, if you want a hash table for objects based on a particular attribute:

```
# @user_objects is a list of objects having a unique_id() method
my %users = map { $_->unique_id() => $_ } @user_objects;
# %users = ( $id => $obj, $id => $obj, ...);
```

It's a really general purpose tool, you have to just start using it to find good uses in your applications.

Some might prefer verbose looping code for readability purposes, but personally, I find `map` more readable.

Comment: I find maps more readable than loops.  Verbosity does not necessarily translate to better readability.

Comment: I agree with you, my intent was to leave that decision to the reader.

Comment: In testing the map function within scripts seems to execute much faster than a loop.

Comment: Map is also a pure solution to the problem.  For is a statement, while map is an expression.  Defining actions as expressions rather than statements reduces side-effects and allows for code that can be threaded or forked far more easily and with less issues.

Answer (score 29):

First of all, it's a simple way of transforming an array: rather than saying e.g.

```
my @raw_values = (...);
my @derived_values;
for my $value (@raw_values) {
    push (@derived_values, _derived_value($value));
}
```

you can say

```
my @raw_values = (...);
my @derived_values = map { _derived_value($_) } @raw_values;
```

It's also useful for building up a quick lookup table: rather than e.g.

```
my $sentence = "...";
my @stopwords = (...);
my @foundstopwords;
for my $word (split(/\s+/, $sentence)) {
    for my $stopword (@stopwords) {
       if ($word eq $stopword) {
           push (@foundstopwords, $word);
       }
    }
}
```

you could say

```
my $sentence = "...";
my @stopwords = (...);
my %is_stopword = map { $_ => 1 } @stopwords;
my @foundstopwords = grep { $is_stopword{$_} } split(/\s+/, $sentence);
```

It's also useful if you want to derive one list from another, but don't particularly need to have a temporary variable cluttering up the place, e.g. rather than

```
my %params = ( username => '...', password => '...', action => $action );
my @parampairs;
for my $param (keys %params) {
    push (@parampairs, $param . '=' . CGI::escape($params{$param}));
}
my $url = $ENV{SCRIPT_NAME} . '?' . join('&amp;', @parampairs);
```

you say the much simpler

```
my %params = ( username => '...', password => '...', action => $action );
my $url = $ENV{SCRIPT_NAME} . '?'
    . join('&amp;', map { $_ . '=' . CGI::escape($params{$_}) } keys %params);
```

(Edit: fixed the missing "keys %params" in that last line)

Comment: I think you left "keys %params" out of your last example.  Also, your stopwords example would probably be better done with a regex instead of split/grep.

Answer (score 22):

The `map` function is used to transform lists. It's basically syntactic sugar for replacing certain types of `for[each]` loops. Once you wrap your head around it, you'll see uses for it everywhere:

```
my @uppercase = map { uc } @lowercase;
my @hex       = map { sprintf "0x%x", $_ } @decimal;
my %hash      = map { $_ => 1 } @array;
sub join_csv { join ',', map {'"' . $_ . '"' } @_ }
```

Answer (score 18):

See also the [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) for advanced usage of map.

Answer (score 12):

It's also handy for making lookup hashes:

```
my %is_boolean = map { $_ => 1 } qw(true false);
```

is equivalent to

```
my %is_boolean = ( true => 1, false => 1 );
```

There's not much savings there, but suppose you wanted to define `%is_US_state`?

Comment: Set::Object is faster and has a better API, however.

Answer (score 12):

**map** is used to create a list by transforming the elements of another list.

**grep** is used to create a list by filtering elements of another list.

**sort** is used to create a list by sorting the elements of another list.

Each of these operators receives a code block (or an expression) which is used to transform, filter or compare elements of the list.

For **map**, the result of the block becomes one (or more) element(s) in the new list. The current element is aliased to $_.

For **grep**, the boolean result of the block decides if the element of the original list will be copied into the new list. The current element is aliased to $_.

For **sort**, the block receives two elements (aliased to $a and $b) and is expected to return one of -1, 0 or 1, indicating whether $a is greater, equal or less than $b.

The [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) uses these operators to efficiently cache values (properties) to be used in sorting a list, especially when computing these properties has a non-trivial cost.

It works by creating an intermediate array which has as elements array references with the original element and the computed value by which we want to sort. This array is passed to sort, which compares the already computed values, creating another intermediate array (this one is sorted) which in turn is passed to another map which throws away the cached values, thus restoring the array to its initial list elements (but in the desired order now).

Example (creates a list of files in the current directory sorted by the time of their last modification):

```
@file_list = glob('*');
@file_modify_times = map { [ $_, (stat($_))[8] ] } @file_list;
@files_sorted_by_mtime = sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } @file_modify_times;
@sorted_files = map { $_->[0] } @files_sorted_by_mtime;
```

By chaining the operators together, no declaration of variables is needed for the intermediate arrays;

```
@sorted_files = map { $_->[0] } sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } map { [ $_, (stat($_))[8] ] } glob('*');
```

You can also filter the list before sorting by inserting a **grep** (if you want to filter on the same cached value):

Example (a list of the files modified in the last 24 hours sorted the last modification time):

```
    @sorted_files = map { $_->[0] } sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } grep { $_->[1] > (time - 24 * 3600 } map { [ $_, (stat($_))[8] ] } glob('*');
```

Answer (score 6):

The map function is an idea from the functional programming paradigm.  In functional programming, functions are first-class objects, meaning that they can be passed as arguments to other functions.  Map is a simple but a very useful example of this.  It takes as its arguments a function (lets call it `f`) and a list `l`.  `f` has to be a function taking one argument, and map simply applies `f` to every element of the list `l`.  `f` can do whatever you need done to every element: add one to every element, square every element, write every element to a database, or open a web browser window for every element, which happens to be a valid URL.

The advantage of using `map` is that it nicely encapsulates iterating over the elements of the list.  All you have to do is say "do `f` to every element, and it is up to `map` to decide how best to do that.  For example `map` may be implemented to split up its work among multiple threads, and it would be totally transparent to the caller.

Note, that `map` is not at all specific to Perl.  It is a standard technique used by functional languages.  It can even be implemented in C using function pointers, or in C++ using "function objects".

Answer (score 5):

The map function runs an expression on each element of a list, and returns the list results.  Lets say I had the following list

```
@names = ("andrew", "bob", "carol" );
```

and I wanted to capitalize the first letter of each of these names.  I could loop through them and call ucfirst of each element, or I could just do the following

```
@names = map (ucfirst, @names);
```

Answer (score 5):

"Just sugar" is harsh.  Remember, a loop is just sugar -- if's and goto can do everything loop constructs do and more.

Map is a high enough level function that it helps you hold much more complex operations in your head, so you can code and debug bigger problems.

Answer (score 4):

To paraphrase "Effective Perl Programming" by Hall & Schwartz,
map can be abused, but I think that it's best used to create a new list from an existing list.

Create a list of the squares of 3,2, & 1:

```
@numbers = (3,2,1);
@squares = map { $_ ** 2 } @numbers;
```

Answer (score 4):

Generate password:

```
$ perl -E'say map {chr(32 + 95 * rand)} 1..16'
# -> j'k=$^o7\l'yi28G
```

Answer (score 4):

You use map to transform a list and assign the results to another list, grep to filter a list and assign the results to another list. The "other" list can be the same variable as the list you are transforming/filtering.

```
my @array = ( 1..5 );
@array = map { $_+5 } @array;
print "@array\n";
@array = grep { $_ < 7 } @array;
print "@array\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

It allows you to transform a list as an *expression* rather than in *statements*. Imagine a hash of soldiers defined like so:

```
{ name          => 'John Smith'
, rank          => 'Lieutenant'
, serial_number => '382-293937-20'
};
```

then you can operate on the list of names separately.

For example,

```
map { $_->{name} } values %soldiers
```

is an *expression*. It can go anywhere an expression is allowed--except you can't assign to it.

```
${[ sort map { $_->{name} } values %soldiers ]}[-1]
```

indexes the array, taking the max.

```
my %soldiers_by_sn = map { $->{serial_number} => $_ } values %soldiers;
```

I find that one of the advantages of operational expressions is that it cuts down on the bugs that come from temporary variables.

If Mr. McCoy wants to filter out all the Hatfields for consideration, you can add that check with minimal coding.

```
my %soldiers_by_sn 
    = map  { $->{serial_number}, $_ } 
      grep { $_->{name} !~ m/Hatfield$/ } 
      values %soldiers
      ;
```

I can continue chaining these expression so that if my interaction with this data has to reach deep for a particular purpose, I don't have to write a lot of code that pretends I'm going to do a lot more.

Answer (score 3):

It's used anytime you would like to create a new list from an existing list.

For instance you could map a parsing function on a list of strings to convert them to integers.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, map creates lists from lists.  Think of "mapping" the contents of one list into another.  Here's some code from a CGI program to take a list of patent numbers and print hyperlinks to the patent applications:

```
my @patents = ('7,120,721', '6,809,505', '7,194,673');
print join(", ", map { "<a href=\"http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=/netahtml/srchnum.htm&r=0&f=S&l=50&TERM1=$_\">$_</a>" } @patents);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, map is most useful for transforming a list.  What hasn't been mentioned is the difference between map and an "equivalent" for loop.

One difference is that for doesn't work well for an expression that modifies the list its iterating over.  One of these terminates, and the other doesn't:

```
perl -e '@x=("x"); map { push @x, $_ } @x'
perl -e '@x=("x"); push @x, $_ for @x'
```

Another small difference is that the *context* inside the map block is a list context, but the for loop imparts a void context.